# How do I reference a method to add to a binaryTree?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am tasked with building a BinaryTree that represents Morse Code. It branches left with each dot and right with each dash.

I can not figure out, however, why my method to add a Node does not seem to want to work with a BinaryTree object. IntelliJ says that it "can not resolve method".

I am certain that the BinaryTree is not the issue, because I was given detailed instructions on how to write the class by my instructor. Rather, I suspect that I am perhaps referencing the wrong thing here. I have already verified that the parameters being entered isn't the issue.

```
 public static MorseCodeTree<Character> readMorseCodeTree()
 {
    MorseCodeTree<Character> morse = new MorseCodeTree<Character>();
    Node<Character> newNode = new Node<Character>(null);
    morse.addNode(newNode, letter, position);

    private Node<Character> addNode(Node<Character> currentNode, char data, String morseCode)
    {
    if (currentNode == null)
    {
        currentNode = new Node(null);
    }

    if (morseCode.charAt(0) == '*')
    {
        currentNode = addNode(currentNode.left, data, morseCode.substring(1));
    }
    else if (morseCode.charAt(0) == '-')
    {
        currentNode = addNode(currentNode.right, data, morseCode.substring(1));
    }
    else
    {
        currentNode.data = data;
    }
    return currentNode;
}
```

BinaryTree class:

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryTree implements Serializable{

```
//implement Node class
protected static class Node<E> implements Serializable
{
    protected E data;
    protected Node<E> left;
    protected Node<E> right;

    public Node (E data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return data.toString();
    }
}
```

protected Node root;

```
public BinaryTree()
{
    root = null;
}

protected BinaryTree(Node<E> root)
{
    this.root = root;
}

public BinaryTree(E data, BinaryTree<E> leftTree, BinaryTree<E> rightTree)
{
    root = new Node<E>(data);
    if (leftTree != null)
    {
        root.left = leftTree.root;
    }
    else
    {
        root.left = null;
    }
    if (rightTree != null)
    {
        root.right = rightTree.root;
    }
    else
    {
        root.right = null;
    }
}

public BinaryTree<E> getLeftSubtree()
{
    if (root != null && root.left != null)
    {
        return new BinaryTree<E>(root.left);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public BinaryTree<E> getRightSubtree()
{
    if (root != null && root.right != null)
    {
        return new BinaryTree<E>(root.right);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public boolean isLeaf()
{
    return (root.left == null && root.right == null);
}

public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    preOrderTraverse(root, 1, sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

private void preOrderTraverse(Node<E> node, int depth, StringBuilder sb)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < depth; i++)
    {
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    if (node == null)
    {
        sb.append("null\n");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.append(node.toString() + "\n");
        preOrderTraverse(node.left, depth + 1, sb);
        preOrderTraverse(node.right, depth + 1, sb);
    }
}

public static BinaryTree<String> readBinaryTree(Scanner scan)
{
    String data = scan.next();
    if (data.equals("null"))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        BinaryTree<String> leftTree = readBinaryTree(scan);
        BinaryTree<String> rightTree = readBinaryTree(scan);
        return new BinaryTree<String>(data, leftTree, rightTree);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you give the exact error that's the compiler throwing.

Comment: Edited to add, but my IDE is telling me "can not resolve method".

Comment: Can you add your `BinaryTree` and `Node` class? I have spotted a few things but need these classes to dig deep and be sure. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring the `addNode(...)` method within `readMorseCodeTree()`, so it's not in the scope of the class. The latter method should look like this:

```java
 public static BinaryTree<Character> readMorseCodeTree()
 {
    BinaryTree morse = new MorseCodeTree();
    Node<Character> newNode = new Node<Character>(null);
    morse.addNode(newNode, letter, position);
 }
```

Comment: That is a good catch, but unfortunately that did not fix the problem.

Comment: @BrineK Is `addNode(...)` being declared in the `BinaryTree` class?

Comment: No? I've provided the BinaryTree class above. MorseCodeTree is a child of BinaryTree.

Comment: @BrineK You're declaring `morse` as a `BinaryTree` object, so `addNode(...)` needs to be declared/implemented in `BinaryTree` (possibly just abstract), or you can just change the declaration to: `MorseCodeTree morse = new MorseCodeTree();`.

Comment: One more thing: I'm getting an incompatible types error for:

currentNode.data = data. (currentNode.data is Character, data is char)

Shouldn't char automatically be wrapped?